# Is there any way to Circle pop-up into full screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I try to animate using height as radius also but that's not working outside screen it seems impossible.
I want to make this circle avatar cover all screen but it stop whenever radius is max to device width/2 or height/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `CircleAvatar` with `Transform.scale()` and increase its `scale` property.

Comment: You are welcome. If you solved your problem please mark the answer as correct.